# How to change the color of the disqus textarea

Tags: html, css, disqus

I simply want to change the color of the textarea in disqus where one can write his comment in disqus.
I spent the last 3 hours in failing to do.

With firebug I was able to change it, and I know what css tags I need to use.

```
#dsq-content .dsq-post-fields .dsq-input-wrapper {  background: #2A2A2A none no-repeat scroll left top; }
```

Everywhere I added this, it just got ignored.

## ATTENTION

I mailed disqus and they sayed that they will introduce a new theme manager soon, bot until then **it is not possible**.

Comment: Good follow-up! Nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try using `!important` on every property</strike>

**Update**: I can't find the classes you are referring to, but I assume you mean to style the "add comment" fields. On cursory inspection, it seems like the  form resides in an iframe, which makes it a separate document and unstylable via your site's CSS.

Comment: @Andrius I'm not entirely sure whether we're on the same page (I can't find the classes you mention in my Disqus example) but I updated my answer. Double-check whether everything is in the same document

Comment: So a service like disqus isn't able to provide a customizable textarea field? On their page they provide a custom css editor, but I couldn't get to work there either.
Do you know any other services similar to disqus which support atleast textarea coloring?

Comment: @Andrius I'm not familiar with the various services that are available. You may need to check them out, and use the element inspector to look how they are structured. One competitor to Disqus  that I know is IntenseDebate.

Comment: I just tried intensedebate out, I was able to do it in 5 minutes (to color the text box).
I really don't know how to put this in a nice way, but disqus just sucks for not letting you customize the textarea. And not putting such valuable information as "Hey You cant colorize the textarea" into the docs made me waste 3 hours.

Comment: @Andrius yeah, that is arguably a big downside. Nice that it worked out!